# What is the built-in properties which are synced one-way in Js?

Tags: javascript, html, dom

I've read an article about the relationship between Attributes and Properties in DOM. They said there are built-in properties which are synced one-way only. So, how do I know which property is one of them?

Comment: Can you link the article? Give a little more information as to what you mean by "Attributes" and "Properties"

Comment: What does "synced one way" mean?

Comment: This is the article which I've read: [link] (http://javascript.info/tutorial/attributes-and-custom-properties)

Comment: @PitaJ You can read it in "Properties and attributes synchronization" part in the link that I have posted.

Comment: This is simply a difference between `properties` and `attributes`

Properties describe the state of an element, attributes describe the code of an element. The `checked` property tells you whether a checkbox is checked, the attribute tells the checkbox to be checked on page load.